# Accessing SQLite in Java Webapp

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to access sqlite.db file in my java web app.
i can access it with absolute path, but now i want to access it with my webapps relative path.
My context.xml looks like

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/webappServer">
    <Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000"
    driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
    url="jdbc:sqlite:/db/sqlite.db" />
</Context>
```

and i call for the connection in my java class

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

my sqlite location is in C:\db\sqlite.db but now i want to move it so i can call my sqlite connection with something like localhost/mysqlite.db
is it possible ? what should i do to achieve it ?

Thanks !

P.S. Im new to java web app. so any help will be very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different ways of doing so:

1. Define the datasource outside your webapps `Context.xml` inside Tomcat's own `Context.xml` and modify it according to the needs of the different servers. One-time configuration on each server required.
2. Solve the problem during your build process. Create different `Context.xml` files for all the environments you need, e.g. `Context_prod.xml`. During the build process identify the file you need and place it in your webapp.

Those are the 2 approaches I am aware of.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. But how to create different context.xml ? and how to declare the url ? can you give me some example ?
Thanks :)

Comment: @jlianto: 1) you just have to create different `Context.xml` files using a simple editor or the IDE of your choice. 2) Defining the URL to your sqllite database depends on your driver (e.g. http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) and should be provided 'somewhere' in the vendors documentation.